# Wordpress post-name permalink redirects to site.com

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, nginx

When permalink is set to `plain` everything works fine. but when I change permalink to `post name`
only Wordpress home page(`dev.site.com/blog`) works fine, but for other pages(e.g., `dev.site.com/blog/first-page`) it will be redirected to `dev.site.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/wordpress-site;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name dev.site.com www.dev.site.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }

    location /blog {
            alias /var/www/wordpress-site/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }
    }

    # angular project

    location / {
            root /home/user/angular-project;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht { deny all; }
}
```

I tried changing `try_files`, but still doesn't work

Thank you :)

Comment: Are these sites using the same codebase and database? WP will redirect to the current canonical URL of a post to avoid duplication and SEO issues

Comment: They are not using same codebase or database . `/` is angular project and `/blog` is wordpress

Comment: I mean site.com vs dev.site.com, you said posts on dev.site.com redirect to site.com, can you edit your question to be clearer, e.g. use example full URLs

Comment: When I change permalink to `post name` page is redirected to `dev.site.com`.

Comment: Oh so all posts redirect to the root, is it a redirect, or are all the permalinks `dev.site.com`? What kind of redirect is it? This doesn't sound like an Apache issue, it sounds like something in PHP/WordPress is doing this.  Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme

Comment: Only `posts` and `pages` redirect to `dev.site.com`,  but `/blog/wp-content/uploads/*` works fine

Comment: Then as I said, the problem is in PHP/WordPress, not Apache. Disable all plugins, switch to the default theme, then enable them 1 by 1 until the problem surfaces again. Are you absolutely sure WordPress is configured with the correct URL in the database, and in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you, it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the second location block:

`location /blog { alias /var/www/wordpress-site/; try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args; }`

`location ~ \.php$ { fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$; include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; include fastcgi_params; fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; }`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, moving `php` block gives 404 even for the homepage

Comment: Did you add in `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;` like above?

Comment: Yes, nothing happened :(